# Canvas creating two separate animated waterfall objects

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to create a template for initiating as many waterfall objects as I wish without having to create a new canvas for each of them. I want two waterfalls with different colors but it doesn't work. I can't figure out why and I'm on it since a few hours. How can I make both red and blue waterfalls appear where the first has a lower z index than the last instantiation?

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var w = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
var h = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

function waterfall(color) {
    var self = this;
  this.color = color;
    this.water = [];
  this.Construct = function(y, vel, acc) {
    this.y = y;
    this.vel = vel;
    this.acc = acc;
  }

  for(var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    this.water.push(new this.Construct(Math.random() * 65, 0.1 + Math.random() * 4.3, 0));
  }

  this.flow = function(color) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    for(var i = 0; i < this.water.length; i++) {
        this.water[i].vel += this.water[i].acc;
        this.water[i].y += this.water[i].vel;
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(0 + i * 0.5, this.water[i].y, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.closePath();
    }
    for(var i = 0; i < this.water.length; i++) {
      if(this.water[i].y > window.innerHeight) {
        this.water[i].y = 0;
      }
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      self.flow.call(self);
    });
  }
  this.flow(this.color)
}

new waterfall("blue");
new waterfall("red");
```

Here's my working code: <del>https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/d9jb08xb/5/</del>

and here again my intention to create two separate waterfalls but this time with the prototype inheritance:

<del>https://jsfiddle.net/testopia/d9jb08xb/8/</del>

I do prefer the latter but I just cant get either working.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are clearing the canvas in each waterfall. One is overpainting the other. You can immediately see that by commenting out the line

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

Of course the water smears that way.

You have to manage your waterfalls in a way that in each animation frame you first clear the canvas then let them paint all.
Here is a quick attempt using a master `flow_all()` function:
https://jsfiddle.net/kpomzs83/

Answer (score 1):

Simply move this line...

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
```

... to here...

```
requestAnimationFrame(function() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);  // ensure that w and h are available here.
    self.flow.call(self);
});
```

This ensures that you do not clear the canvas before the 2nd waterfall is drawn. This clears the canvas, then draws the two waterfalls. Make sure you've added them to your water array, of course.